# Change value in one dataframe if it matches in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created 2 Pandas DataFrame

[DataFrame1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qS6P.png)

[DataFrame2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NfGi.png)

DataFrame1.Number contains wrong values but DataFrame2.Number contains right values.

I want to replace value of DataFrame1.Number to values in DataFrame2.Number if all the columns values gets matched, i.e.

```
DataFrame2.Name == DataFrame1.Name and
DataFrame2.Value1 == DataFrame1.Value1 and
DataFrame2.Value2 == DataFrame1.Value2 and
DataFrame2.Value3 == DataFrame1.Value3 and
DataFrame2.Value4 == DataFrame1.Value4
```

Expected Result in DataFrame1: [DataFrame1 Expected Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQgFP.png)

I am unable to achieve required result. Please Help!!!

Comment: Can you try and post your data in a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) format please? No one will spend time recreating your datasets from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge on  `Name`, `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3` and `Value4` columns, then use [pandas.DataFrame.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update `df1` `Number` column according to the merged `Number_y` column which is from the `df2` dataframe.

```py
df1["Number"].update(df1.merge(df2, on=["Name", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"], how="outer")["Number_y"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df3=pd.merge(d1,df2, how='left', on='Name')
```

Also please review [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Hi, Eren Han. Thanks for the reply but this would create a dataframe of shape (37, 11). This is not I wanted.

Comment: hey did you try df=df3[['column1','column2',....]] ?